# My char arrays cut off at 318 character using Visual Studios 2017 C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2017, size, string-length

Hello All I have a problem where my `char arrays (strings)` won't display anything past `318 characters`. If I do a `std::string` it's fine and displays the whole thing... but if I try to convert it to a char array using `std::string.c_str()` it only produces the first `318 characters` again. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using `Visual Studio 2017`. The actual string length is `517chars`.

Example...

```
std::string x = "INSERT INTO oms.Customers (customerFirstName, CustomerMiddleInitial, customerLastName, customerPrefixSuffix, customerCompanyName, customerStreetReference, customerStreetAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip, CountryID, customerPhoneNumber, customerEmail, customerIsCompany, customerIsActive) Values('Bill', '
INSERT INTO oms.Customers(customerFirstName, CustomerMiddleInitial, customerLastName, customerPrefixSuffix, customerCompanyName, customerStreetReference, customerStreetAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip, CountryID, customerPhoneNumber, customerEmail, customerIsCompany, customerIsActive)Values('Bill', ' ', 'Cosby', '', 'The Cosby Show', 'Studio A', '1818 broadway st', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '19809', '', '6169875942', 'Bill.Cosby@ididntdoit.com', '', ');SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];"
```

but if I make any type of char array such as if I did

```
char *y;
y= x.c_str
```

only the below will show

```
INSERT INTO oms.Customers (customerFirstName, CustomerMiddleInitial, customerLastName, customerPrefixSuffix, customerCompanyName, customerStreetReference, customerStreetAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip, CountryID, customerPhoneNumber, customerEmail, customerIsCompany, customerIsActive) Values('Bill', '
```

if I do `strlen(y)` I get `318`. If I do `x.length()` I get `517`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: why don't you do char y[1000000]?  You can easily set the size of the char array that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` may contain `'\0'` characters, which will be identified as C-style `NUL` terminated string end markers by `strlen(y)`.
That's why the results are different for `strlen()` and `std::string::length()`.

Comment: Thanks that was it!

Answer (score -1):

If I make the string raw:

```
std::string x = R"(INSERT INTO oms.Customers (customerFirstName, CustomerMiddleInitial, customerLastName, customerPrefixSuffix, customerCompanyName, customerStreetReference,
        customerStreetAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip, CountryID, customerPhoneNumber, customerEmail, customerIsCompany, customerIsActive) Values('Bill',
        '

            INSERT INTO oms.Customers(customerFirstName, CustomerMiddleInitial, customerLastName, customerPrefixSuffix, customerCompanyName, customerStreetReference,
                customerStreetAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip, CountryID, customerPhoneNumber, customerEmail, customerIsCompany, customerIsActive)Values('Bill',
                    ' ', 'Cosby', '', 'The Cosby Show', 'Studio A', '1818 broadway st', 'Philadelphia', 'PA', '19809', '', '6169875942', 'Bill.Cosby@ididntdoit.com', '', ');SELECT
                    SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS[SCOPE_IDENTITY]; )";
                    char const *pStr = x.c_str();
                    _RPTA("strlen: %d\r\n", strlen(pStr));
```

the length prints as 857 (_RPTA is a custom macro that prints to the VS debug trace rather than the program console like printf would).